# Node JS Pass a Variable to Jade / Pug

Tags: node.js, pug

For some reason I can't pass a variable to the pug template with Node JS.

```
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.render('index', { hello : 'Hey'} )
})
```

....

```
extends layout.pug

block content
    h1 #{hello} guy
```

This just returns "guy" in the index.html file

Comment: can you put more code? what is `app`? what does `layout.pug` have?

Answer (score 23):

I think you are using JADE coding (#{hello}) with "pug"(updated jade) plugin with static .html -- completely wrong.

Follow the lines below:

1. Use this first

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/public/views');
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
```

2. Then pass this to first visit

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   res.render('index', { title: 'Hey', message: 'Hello there!'});
});
```

3. Then echo in template file "index.pug" in "/public/views"

```
html
  head
  title= title
body
  h1= message
```

Comment: give me your directory structure snapshot

+

show me your server file with

app.set('views', __dirname + '/public/views');
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
than pass this to first visit
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Hey', message: 'Hello there!'});
});

Comment: Now it just says "Express" https://github.com/jpking72/nodejsfiddle.git

Comment: i'm having the same issue, and apparently @Seetpalsingh not sure what TheHawk and i are not getting right.

Answer (score 15):

Try this.. works for me.

**nodejs part / index.js**

```
const router = require('express').Router();
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    const testObj = {hello: 'Hey'};
    res.render('index', { testObj: JSON.stringify(testObj) });
});
```

**pug/jade part / (index.pug)**

```
script.
    var testObj = !{testObj};
```

i'm using **pug** version: 2.0.3